# This Supybot for windows batch install script needs to create another batch file

Tags: batch-file, find, set, irc, bots

This Supybot for windows batch install script needs to create another batch file...

**The Problem**:

(1) I have a directory that has a file that ends with .conf

(2) There is only one file in this directory that ends with .conf

(3) But I don't know what this file starts with.. all I know is ????????.conf

(4) How do I set the filename.conf and remove the .conf part of the file name?

(5) As it is just the beginning of the filename that I need.

Example:

C:\runbot>find "supybot.ident: " | type *.conf > temp.txt

robotbot.conf

Outputs : robotbot.conf

The quest, is how do I set a variable=robotbot

=========================================================================

**The Input** was this file named "RootCode.conf" among many others 
within the directory searched:

RootCode.conf

**The Solution** is:

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in ('FINDSTR /M "supybot.ident:" *.conf') DO SET USER=%%a&set dontneed=%%b

echo %USER%

pause

**The Output** is:

C:\runbot>FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %a in ('FINDSTR /M "supybot.ident:" *.con
f') DO SET USER=%a  & set dontneed=%b

C:\runbot>SET USER=RootCode  & set dontneed=conf

C:\runbot>echo RootCode
RootCode

C:\runbot>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

Winner... Special thanks Everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example of piping the output to `type`command is either wrong or useless. So I am assuming you mistyped and the real line was piping the other way around, and thus I am assuming that you are trying to find the filename of the file that contains the string "supybot.ident: ". In that case I would suggest to use `findstr` command instead.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('FINDSTR /M "supybot.ident:" *.conf') DO SET USER=%%a
```

See `HELP FINDSTR`, `HELP SET` and `HELP FOR` for more information.

Comment: Now that you have found me a solution: can you help me with a title that would make it more clear. I can not think of what to call this little script that you made up? Special thanks... Edoctoor

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear (to me, at least) what exactly you ask here. But if you need the output of a command, then use `for /f`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('some command ^| line') do set somevar=%%x
```

Note that you need to escape shell metacharacters in the command line (as they need to survive one parsing pass). Also note that you cannot set a variable to contain more than one line of text.